# AlertDialog в android

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment

Есть вот такой код:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String success) {
        super.onPostExecute(success);

        String LOG_TAG = "Login_JSON_Array";
        String confirm = null;

        try{
            JSONObject status = new JSONObject(success);
            String auto = status.getString("auto");
            if(auto == "true"){
                confirm = status.getString("confirm");
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, confirm);
            }
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, auto);
            if (auto == "true") {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("confirm", confirm);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else if(auto == "no_register") {
                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                Register_Dialog registerNow = new Register_Dialog();
                registerNow.show(manager, "dialog");
            }else if(auto == "false") {
                setTextError(mPasswordView, R.string.error_incorrect_password);
                setErrorIcon(mEmailView);
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Ошибка при получении данных: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public static class Register_Dialog extends DialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String title = "";
        String message = getString(R.string.register_now);
        String button1String = getString(R.string.str_reg);
        String button2String = getString(R.string.str_otl);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);

        builder.setPositiveButton(button1String, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(button2String, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //отложить
            }
        });
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

и проблема в том что при срабатывании no_register диалоговое окно не показывается. Скажите в чем проблема??

Comment: вместо == в условии if лучше использовать equals

Comment: это может и лучше, но остальные if срабатывают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно все заработало стоило только в if '==' заменить на equals.